# Como controlar um RadioButtonList via código

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, radiobutton

Estou usando C# asp.net web forms

Tenho dois RadioButtonList

```html
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblGrupo" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CellPadding="5" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblGrupo_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                            <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Geral</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem>Por Grupo</asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:RadioButtonList>

<asp:RadioButtonList Enabled="false" ID="rblSubGrupo" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CellPadding="5" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblSubGrupo_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                                <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Geral</asp:ListItem>
                                                <asp:ListItem>Por Sub-Grupo</asp:ListItem>
                                            </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Um com `Geral` e `Por Grupo` e o outro com `Geral` e `Por SubGrupo`

Eu queria que quando o `Geral` do Grupo fosse selecionado, automaticamente o `Geral` do Sub Grupo fosse selecionado também.

Supondo que a pessoa escolheu primeiro um grupo e um subgrupo, mas depois ela quer apenas um grupo, nessa situação eu gostaria que o Sub Grupo fosse marcado o `Geral`

Comment: Você pode setar o outro geral, no OnClick do Geral do Grupo. Lá você seleciona ele.

Comment: É justamente essa a minha vida, como fazer isso ? Poderia postar algum exemplo de código por favor ?

Answer (score 1):

Algo mais ou menos assim:

```
if(Grupo.Checked){
 SubGrupo.Checked = true
else
 SubGrupo.Checked = false;
}
```

Ou assim:

```
boolean radio;  
radio =  radiobutton.isSelected();
```

ai você verifica:

```
if(radio == true) { //selecionado }  
else { //nullo }
```

Veja se resolve seu problema

Vi que você usa o RadioButtonList, então seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
if(RadioGrupo.SelectedIndex == 0){
 radiosubgrupo.selectedindex = 0
else
....
}
```